# how handle exception using IMDBPY

Tags: python, exception, information-retrieval, imdb, imdbpy

this code works perfect with movie Id that has plot keyword .

```
from imdb import IMDb
ia = IMDb()
black_panther = ia.get_movie('1825683', info='keywords')
print(black_panther['keywords'])
```

bur for movies that haven't plot keyword like this id(5950092) it returns exception.any idea for handle exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `imdb.Movie.Movie` is a subclass of `imdb.utils._Container` with a `get` method similar to [that of a `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get), and which docstring reads:

```
>>> imdb.utils._Container.get.__doc__
"Return the given section, or default if it's not found."
```

That means you can do this to never throw an exception if there are no keywords:

```
movie = ia.get_movie('5950092', info='keywords')

movie.get('keywords', [])
# Result: [], empty list
```

You can also work with an `Exception` if you want to:

```
try:
    keywords = movie['keywords']
except KeyError:
    keywords = []
```

Comment: I have the same  problem for movie language .would you help me.

Comment: movie = ia.get_movie('5950092', info='language') not working.

Comment: Because `'language'` is not included in the movie infoset, i.e., try `'language' in ia.get_movie_infoset()`. It should be `False`.

Answer (score 0):

In IMDbPY, Movie instances behave like dictionaries, so you handle exceptions in the usual way (with a try/except clause).  See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Being dictionary-like objects, you can also test for the presence of a key with `'keywords' in black_panther` and get the value without raising n exception, but returning None if the key is missing, with `black_panther.get('keywords')`.